Python Azure function Kafka Triggered - autoOffsetReset as Latest in host.json not working
When I do new deployment, my kafka triggered func app starts ingesting data from past 7 days. It takes immense amount of time. So, I want to read data and insert to database with the latest data and not from the start.Therefore, I am using autoOffsetReset flag as latest (assuming this parameter fulfills my requirement)My host.json file
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "kafka": {
      "autoOffsetReset": "latest"
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}

Function.json --- EVENT HUB
{
      "scriptFile": "main.py",
      "bindings": [
        {
            "type" : "kafkaTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name" : "kevents",
            "protocol" : "SASLSSL",
            "password" : "EventHubConnectionString",
            "topic" : "message_python",
            "authenticationMode" : "PLAIN",
            "cardinality" : "MANY",
            "dataType": "string",
            "consumerGroup" : "$Default",
            "username" : "$ConnectionString",
            "BrokerList" : "%BrokerList%"    
        }
    ]
}


main.py
import logging
import typing
from azure.functions import KafkaEvent

def main(kevents : typing.List[KafkaEvent]):
    for event in kevents:
        logging.info(event.get_body())

I have tried different host.json settings but I am unable to read latest events when doing new deployments. Instead, it reads past 7 days data.
EDIT
I am now not sure what to do. I am getting this warning (see the image)
Host.json code is above. I am pasting the image here

According to the official documentation, I can use it here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-kafka?tabs=isolated-process%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python

I checked my function runtime version


Try setting the property "auto.offset.reset" : "latest" in host.json.

Okay, I will try this today. But this parameter pattern does not match with other parameters. Most of these are in camel case
